# How Would You Recursively Get All The Combinations Of Items Within A List

Tags: python, list, recursion

In my attempt, I have a list: "stuff" that is supposed to be iterated over recursively to find all possible combinations. It does this by trying to recurse on all items except the first, trying to recurse on all items except the [1] index (rollover), and finally iterating over all items except the [2] index (ollie).

```
stuff = ['1','2','3','4','5']

def rollOver(aL):
  neuList = []
  neuList.append(aL[0])
  neuList.extend(aL[2:])
  return neuList

def ollie(aL):
  neuList = []
  neuList.extend(aL[0:1])
  neuList.extend(aL[3:])
  return neuList

def recurse(info):
  try:
    if len(info) == 3:
      print(info)
    if len(info) > 1:
      recurse(info[1:])
      recurse(rollOver(info))
      recurse(ollie(info))
  except:
    l = 0

recurse(stuff)
```

I manually tried this method on paper and it seemed to work. However, in the code I get the results:

```
['3', '4', '5']
['2', '4', '5']
['3', '4', '5']
['1', '4', '5']
['1', '4', '5']
```

1, 3, 5 should be a listed possibility, but it doesn't show up, which leads me to think I've done something wrong.

Comment: Do you know about [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)?

Comment: I do, but the project I'm implementing this in is supposed to be more of a "breadth of knowledge" deal so I can get internships.

Comment: offtopic but why is every word in the title is capitalized?

Comment: You are creating the combinations of your input, perhaps you want to use [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations); `combinations(stuff, 3)`.

Comment: The nice thing about the documentation for that library is the 'python equivalents' listed.

Comment: @ishidex2 Thats how I was taught titles were supposed to be formatted from gradeschool

Comment: Next, **don't play Pokemon**. Remove that blanket `except` call. You are masking errors in your code by caching em all.

Comment: I did that because thats how my data structures teacher had us do a project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is via the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) package:

```
from itertools import combinations

stuff = ['1','2','3','4','5']

for i in combinations(stuff, 3):
    print(i)
```

Which gives you the desired output:

```
('1', '2', '3')
('1', '2', '4')
('1', '2', '5')
('1', '3', '4')
('1', '3', '5')
('1', '4', '5')
('2', '3', '4')
('2', '3', '5')
('2', '4', '5')
('3', '4', '5')
```

Alternatively, if you want to code this yourself in a recursive fashion, you could implement your own function as follows:

```
def combs(stuff):
    if len(stuff) == 0:
        return [[]]
    cs = []
    for c in combs(stuff[1:]):
        cs += [c, c+[stuff[0]]]
    return cs
```

I'll leave it to you to edit this function to only return results of a given size.